# Is there any library/extension to encode a txt file into a HTML file safely so that I won't need to load it by AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I am loading a txt file (in utf-8) by $.ajax (I am using jQuery)

The txt file contains some break lines, for instance:

```
line1

line2
line3
```

If I load it via AJAX to a variable it will be:

```
line1\n\nline2\nline3
```

I can just replace break lines with \n or any other symbols for this case but for very complicated txt files, it's very risky.

Is there any library or function that can encode a txt file directly into a string that I can directly put in use like:

```
$ convert-to-string a.txt
output in a text file:
var s = 'line1\n\nline2\nline3';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript:

1. Convert to JSON (many libraries for many languages are available)
2. Ensure that you don't have anything which might break a script element (like `</script>`
3. Output `<script> var foo = $results_of_above_steps; </script>`

Some JSON libraries will automatically escape `/` characters as `\/` which deals with number 2 for you, if yours does not then you should do that as a separate step.